# Angularjs, watching variable value change

Tags: angularjs

I have the AngularJS module declaration as below. Here I have declared value **AppModel**. 
I wanted to write code which will be triggered when `AppModel.currentTable` is changed, How can I **watch** for this value change ?

```
angular.module('MIIApp', ['MIIServices']).
value("AppModel",{
    currentTable:"TESTME-h",
    currentUser:null
});
```

Any help!!!.

Comment: I found a solution, I have attached the "watcher" like below, Let me know if there is a better way

run(function($rootScope, AppModel) {
    $rootScope.AppModel = AppModel;
    $rootScope.$watch("AppModel.currentTable", function(){
        alert("currentable chagned : "+AppModel.currentTable);
    });
});

Comment: Its not very consistent, some times this event is not fired at all,  I tried updating the model value from a 'directive' but the event is not fired, But If I try to update the value from a 'controller' it works, Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you should be doing this. As you can see [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide#value) a value is intended to be a constant:

> value(name, value)
>
> A short hand for configuring services if the $get method is a
>   constant.

In AngularJS a service is a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and a value is the most simple of the possible services, when called returns always the same.
I don’t know what you need, but could it be you are confusing models with services?